# How can I test re-ordering a table using Instruments and UI Automation?

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I am using UI Automation to develop test cases for my app.  One of the actions I need to test is to put a table into 'edit' mode and then re-order cells in the table.

I am able to navigate to the view and tap on the 'edit' button I put into the navigationBar.

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to drag on the screen properly.

I found the UIElement that is the table view (app.mainWindow().tables()[0]) and performed a drag with:

```
table.dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0.8, y:0.3}, endOffset:{x:0.8, y:0.8}, duration:1.5});
```

However, the table needs to have a touch and hold on the cell's handle, then drag.  I don't see how to perform such an action.

Anyone figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the same problem with 'Drag and Drop'. First of all you need to try to drag not a table but cell in it. The second point is timeout. As usual application has timeout to react on drag (touch and hold). it can be like 1 or 2 seconds for this operation. Try to increase timeout parameter for dragFromToForDuration. For my application it was enough to set 6 - 8 seconds.

Try to implement your own function that will take 2 parameters. First parameter - cell object you want to drag. Second parameter - another cell object where you dragged cell will be dropped. NOTE that this function will work **only** if both of *FROM* and *TO* objects will be visible on the screen.

```
function reorderCellsInTable(from, to)
{
    if ( from.checkIsValid() && to.checkIsValid() )
    {
        if ( !from.isVisible() )
        {
            from.scrollToVisible();
            //put 1 second delay if needed
        }
        var fromObjRect = from.rect();
        // setting drag point into the middle of the cell. You may need to change this point in order to drag an object from required point. 
        var sourceX = fromObjRect.origin.x + fromObjRect.size.width/2;
        var sourceY = fromObjRect.origin.y + fromObjRect.size.height/2;
        var toObjRect = to.rect();
        // setting drop point into the middle of the cell. The same as the drag point - you may meed to change the point to drop bellow or above the drop point
        var destinationX = toObjRect.origin.x + toObjRect.size.width/2;
        var destinationY = toObjRect.origin.y + toObjRect.size.height/2;

        UIATarget.localTarget().dragFromToForDuration({x:sourceX, y:sourceY}, {x:destinationX, y:destinationY}, 8);
        }
    }
```

For example you have 5 cells. You need to drag the second one and to put it at the end. Example of function call:

```
var cellToReorder = tableView()[<your table view>].cells()[<cell#2NameOrIndex>];
var cellToDrop = tableView()[<your table view>].cells()[<cell#5NameOrIndex>];
reorderCellsInTable(cellToReorder, cellToDrop);
```